# Handling browser refresh in Extjs when route is present in URL

Tags: extjs

We are developing an application which is purely driven by data. Most of the times data is maintained in sessions to handle the behavior after refresh.

But due to security reasons we don't want to maintain data is session.

One approach to achieve this is:
1. Create a utitlty(singleton) class and maintain data in it.
2. Handle onbeforeunload and load events of browser. In onbeforeunload event push all data from singleton to sessionstorage and in load pullback from sessionstorage and clear session.

But the issue here is, when any routes are present in application URL then onbeforeunload event is not triggered.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Which extjs version & browser are u using ,bcoz I am able to fire event properly.

Comment: @Tejas
Extjs 6.2 Classic

Comment: Can you create simple fiddle for your issue